Unable to compile NASM without -no_pie on macOS
I'm trying to follow the tutorial for NASM and I made a few adjustments (like changing the entrypoint function from "start" to "_main") to get the following hello.asm to compile and run on macOS 14.5 (64-bit):
          global    _main

          section   .text
_main:    mov       rax, 0x02000004         ; system call for write
          mov       rdi, 1                  ; file handle 1 is stdout
          mov       rsi, message            ; address of string to output
          mov       rdx, 13                 ; number of bytes
          syscall                           ; invoke operating system to do the write
          mov       rax, 0x02000001         ; system call for exit
          xor       rdi, rdi                ; exit code 0
          syscall                           ; invoke operating system to exit

          section   .data
message:  db        "Hello, World", 10      ; note the newline at the end

To compile and run it I'm executing:
nasm -fmacho64 hello.asm && gcc -Wl,-no_pie hello.o -o hello && ./hello

It prints "Hello World" (hooray) - however the linking process produces a warning, and I'm wondering if there's any way to resolve it:
ld: warning: -no_pie is deprecated when targeting new OS versions
ld: warning: alignment (1) of atom '_main' is too small and may result in unaligned pointers

If I try compiling the assembly without -Wl,-no_pie then I get a bus error:
ld: warning: alignment (1) of atom '_main' from '/Users/rybickic/Developer/nasm-hacks/hello.o' is too small and may result in unaligned pointers 
ld: warning: no platform load command found in '/Users/rybickic/Developer/nasm-hacks/hello.o', assuming: macOS
ld: warning: disabling chained fixups because of unaligned pointers
ld: warning: pointer not aligned at _main+0xC from /Users/rybickic/Developer/nasm-hacks/hello.o
[1]    58589 bus error  ./hello


You want lea rsi, [rel message]

Replacing mov rsi, message with that line fixed it. Thanks!

Near duplicate of How to load address of function or label into register - the best way to load an address is RIP-relative, if you can't use 32-bit absolute.  64-bit absolute like you were using here is the worst choice for efficiency even when you use no_pie to make it work at all.  But not actually a duplicate because that Q&A doesn't say anything about why macOS won't do text relocations at runtime to fixup the 64-bit absolute address as an immediate.
